# Non-equivalent categories

Tags: category-theory

Let $C$ be a category and let $D$ be a subcategory of $C$ with the same objects. Assume that the inclusion functor from $D$ to $C$ is not full. Can we deduce that the categories $C$ and $D$ are not equivalent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*That* functor is not an equivalence, obviously. But otherwise you can't say anything. For instance, consider the case where $\mathcal{C}$ has objects $\ldots, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots$ and a unique morphism $n \to m$ if and only if $n = m$ or $0 \le n \le m$. Let $\mathcal{D}$ be the subcategory with same objects but omitting the unique morphism $0 \to m$ for all $m > 0$. Then $\mathcal{D}$ is *isomorphic* to $\mathcal{C}$, by relabelling the objects.

Comment: I try to show that $\mathcal{D}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathcal{C}$. Assume that there are two functors $F: \mathcal{D} \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ and $G : \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ such that $F \circ G = id_{\mathcal{C}}$ and $G  \circ F = id_{\mathcal{D}}$.

Comment: We have $0 \leq 0 \leq 2$ and $0 \leq 1 \leq 2$, hence there are morphisms $0 \rightarrow 2$ and $1 \rightarrow 2$ in $\mathcal{D}$, hence $0 \leq F(0) \leq F(2)$ and $0 \leq F(1) \leq F(2)$. Hence (a) $0 \leq F(0) < F(1)$ or (b) $0 \leq F(1) < F(0)$. With (a) we obtain in $\mathcal{D}$ a morphism $0 \rightarrow 1$ and with (b) a morphism $1 \rightarrow 0$ in $\mathcal{D}$.

Comment: Maybe you wanted to consider the category $\mathcal{D}$ obtained from $\mathcal{C}$ by omitting all the morphisms $0 \rightarrow x$ for $x > 0$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.